# Javascript regexp for smile images replacements

Tags: javascript, regex

i need replace   `{smile:smilename}` to it's image tag with src
`<img src="/img/smile/smilename.gif">`

i'm trying:

```
data['text'] = 'text{smile:smile3}text{smile:smile3}text{smile:smile3}text';     
data['text'] = data['text'].replace('/{smile:(.*?)}/g', '<img src="/img/smile/$1.gif">');
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's no regex, it's a string literal! Remove the quotes around your regex.

Instead of your current code:

```
.replace('/{smile:(.*?)}/g', ...);
```

Use:

```
.replace(/{smile:(.*?)}/g, ...);
```

You current code is trying to replace the literal string `/{smile:(.*?)}/g`, which obviously does not appear in your input string.